# javascript/Ajax only working when debugging

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I wanted to remove the user session and related data when the user closes the browser. i referred to this (http://weblogs.asp.net/kaushal/archive/2011/02/25/user-is-trying-to-leave-trap-and-set-confirm-alert-on-browser-tab-close-event.aspx) post and i have some coding as below. I wanted to delete the user data from the application state and SQL server database when the user closes the browser. And i am doing this with the help of a handler.
The below code is working fine while debugging, it is calling the handler and executing all the codes which i have written in to it. But when i really use this app this is not working. I don't know where the problem is. And it is eating my time. 
(I am using this inside the content of a Master page)

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {


    var UserID = '<%= Session["UserID"] %>';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../Handlers/HandlerUser.ashx?Action=RemoveUserDataOnBrowserClose&UserID=" + UserID.toString(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });

}
```

if any one can suggest another way to achieve the same, it will be a great help.

Comment: How can you be sure that it is not working when you're not debugging? Do you log what happens inside the httphandler?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. the handler has to delete a data from database which it is not doing...

Comment: I would recommend [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). A highly flexible logging utility for .Net

Comment: If you call the url manually, does it delete the data then?

Comment: When i debug, it is deleting... I put breakpoints and checked it. it is working fine then....

Comment: If you call mysite.com/Handlers/HandlerUser.ashx?Action=RemoveUserDataOnBrowserClose&UserID=123?

Comment: Yes... I tried like you said. It is working fine then

Comment: Is your issue is solved or not?

Comment: No. i cannot find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i got the answer. My problem was my handlers were not calling and it was because i didn't add Forms Authentication to my app. I added this code after authentication and it worked fine.

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserID, false);
```

I didn't knew that this was necessary.Thanks every one for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it is not working because it is asynchronous call.
the function exits before the call happens.

I suggest you interrupt the closing action, clean the data from your database and than after in your callback you call the closing event programmatically.

I found this [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/hmloo/archive/2012/02/15/use-window.onbeforeunload-event-to-stop-browser-from-closing-or-disable.aspx) which might help you.

Comment: I think i have done same as your suggested post. Can we do it synchronously?